# mongodb: cannot set property as null though its working in shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build OTP generation and verification module with
Nodejs,mongodb,Nexmo

BUT IT IS WORKING IN SHELL

here is my code

**PHONE SHCHEMA**

```
    const phoneSchema = new Schema({
    mobileNo:{type: String},
    count:{type:String},
    verified:{
        type:String,
        defaultValue:0
        },
    lastFive:{
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now
        },
 },{ timestamps: true})
const Phone = mongoose.model('Phone', phoneSchema)
module.exports = Phone
```

**OTP SCHEMA**

```
const otpSchema = new Schema({
   otp:{
        type:Number,
        unique: true
},
    mobileNo:{ type:String,}
},{ timestamps: true})
const Otp = mongoose.model('Otp', otpSchema)
module.exports = Otp
```

**LOGIN CONTROLLER**

```
const nexmo = new Nexmo({
  apiKey: '#######',
  apiSecret: '########'
})
exports.getOtp = async (req,res,next)=>{
    try{
       const {mobileNo} = req.body 
         let phone = await MobileNo.findOne({mobileNo})
if(!phone){        
       const error = new Error('Number you have entered is not registered Please contact dealer')
       throw error
}
else{
     Otp.findOneAndDelete({mobileNo})
        const dates= phone.lastFive.toString().split(';')
        if(dates.length>=5){
            const msec=(Date.now()- parseInt(dates[0]) )
            const minute=Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60)
            if(minute<=5){
                return res.json({
                    err:'5 minute 5 Otp limit. Wait'
                })
            }else{
                phone.count++;
                phone.lastFive=Date.now();
            }}
        else{
            phone.count++;
            phone.lastFive=`${phone.lastFive} ${Date.now()}`
        }}

    let  otp,randomOtp;
    while(true){
    randomOtp = Math.floor( Math.random() * (10000 - 1000) + 1000)
    otp = await Otp.findOne({otp} )
    if(!otp){
        otp = new Otp({
            otp:randomOtp,
            mobileNo
        })
       setTimeout(()=>{
            otp.delete();
        },1000*60*5);
        break}}
const from = 'Nexmo'
const to = mobileNo
const text = `Verification code :- ${randomOtp}`
nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text,async (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      await phone.save()
       await otp.save()
        res.json({
            msg:'OTP is send Successfuly',
            success:true
        })   
 }
  })}
    catch(err){
        next(err)}}

VERIFYING OTP

exports.verifyOtp= async(req,res,next)=>{
    const {otp,mobileNo}= req.body;
    try{
const checkOtp = await Otp.findOne({otp,mobileNo});
       if(!checkOtp){
           throw new Error('Invalid Otp')
        }
        else
        {
            const findPhone = await MobileNo.findOne({ mobileNo:checkOtp.mobileNo,otp} )  
           findPhone.verified=1;
            findPhone.save();
            checkOtp.delete();
                return res.json({
                msg:'OTP is verified',
                success:true
            })}}
        catch(err){
            next(err)}}
```

** ROUTE **

```
const loginController = require('../controllers/loginController')
router.post('/getotp', loginController.getOtp)
router.post('/verifyotp', loginController.verifyOtp)
module.exports = router
```

** ERROR**

> findPhone null TypeError: Cannot set property 'verified' of null 
>       at exports.verifyOtp (######\backend\src\controllers\loginController.js:164:31)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
>   <

Comment: hello, it looks that your line `const findPhone = await MobileNo.findOne({ mobileNo:checkOtp.mobileNo,otp})` is returning null and then you try to modify the field `verified` inside the null value which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks Theo i have removed the "otp" parameter and it worked